# If statement not working Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

EDIT: Yeah, I have been coding in python lately and iv mixed up the syntax between the two languages. Thanks for the improvement tips.

My goal is to get the if statements working and output the corresponding normal, medium and hard. Eventhough GameDifficulty is set to 2, it outputs hard instead of medium. I have noticed that it just outputs the last if statement bit. Its really weird.

I define GameDifficulty as 2. When i run the script, Text11 becomes "hard" instead of Medium. I have no idea why this happens.

Thank you

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class DifficultyDisplayOnWinScreen : MonoBehaviour {
    public int GameDifficulty;
    public GameObject Text11;
    public string diffi;
    void Start () 
    {

        //GameDifficulty = DifficultyChooser.DifficultyNumber;
        GameDifficulty = 2;

    }

    void Update () 
    {
        //GameDifficulty = DifficultyChooser.DifficultyNumber;
        if (GameDifficulty == 3);
        {
            Text11.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Normal";
        }       
        if (GameDifficulty == 2);
        {
            Text11.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Medium";
        }
        if (GameDifficulty == 1);
        {
            Text11.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Hard";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't read your question yet, but hey, do not make statements that big, it is most probably your logic behind not working than `if` operator.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Unity, but I think it is because you have `;` at the end of your `if` statements.

Comment: _Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence_

Comment: This doesn't really warrant an answer, an understanding of how if statements work would resolve this issue.  The `;` at the end of your if statements is closing them out and not adding the body, therefore the `{}` around your `getComponent` (Which would be cheaper if you just made Text11 a `Text` type) is automatically run.  you can prove this by removing your if statements altogether and get the same result.

Comment: Just flag it as _off-topic-typo_ @Eddge

Comment: @User453465436754 I was going to just couldn't remember where the simple "typographic" flag was.  Thanks!

Comment: @Eddge lol. no problem good sir

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `;` after the `if`-conditions:

```
if (GameDifficulty == 3)
{
    Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Normal";
}
if (GameDifficulty == 2)
{
    Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Medium";
}
if (GameDifficulty == 1)
{
    Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Hard";
}
```

Explanation: the `;` ends the `if` statement, making it an empty statement. This is because one-line `if` statements are allowed in C#, and the `;` determines where they end.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: I didn't even notice the `;`s, yeah remove semicolons and it should work.

```
if (GameDifficulty == 3)
{
    Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Normal";
}       
if (GameDifficulty == 2)
{
    Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Medium";
}
if (GameDifficulty == 1) //if there is only 3 difficulties in this line you can use just else
{
    Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Hard";
}
```

Or use `if/else`

```
if (GameDifficulty == 3)
{
    Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Normal";
}       
else if (GameDifficulty == 2)
{
    Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Medium";
}
else if (GameDifficulty == 1) //if there is only 3 difficulties in this line you can use just else
{
    Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Hard";
}
```

and in this case better use `switch/case`:

```
switch(GameDifficulty)
{
    case 1:
        Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Hard";
        break;

    case 2:
        Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Medium";
        break;

    case 3:
        Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Normal";
        break;
}
```

or you can have a dictionary of difficulties for example:

```
Dictionary<int, string> difficulties = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    {1, "Hard" },
    {2, "Medium" },
    {3, "Normal" }
};
```

and use it like:

```
Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = difficulties[GameDifficulty];
```

Or `enum` (there is tons of ways to make it more readable and simple, so I will end my examples with this one)

```
enum Difficulties
{
    Hard = 1,
    Medium = 2,
    Normal = 3
}
```

usage:

```
Text11.GetComponent<Text>().text = ((Difficulties)GameDifficulty).ToString();
```

Comment: @User453465436754 Well, yea thanks. The other 2 or 3 parts of my answer is more like an advice or something.

Comment: That's fine.  There is precedence for advice in SO :)